# How to set default tab in Smart Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, default, tabview

I am using [Smart Tab Layout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) for `Android`. I have 4 tabs namely `A, B, C` and `D.` By default, the focus is on `Tab A`. How do I get to change the default to Tab B without changing the order of the tabs.

Comment: Did you tri with setting current item of your ViewPager to the second one?

Comment: Hi, I'm going to use SmartTabLayout but It's example consist of all property and i just need one of them like "always in Center". I've wrote the code but Tabs and Page not sync to each other. Is it possible share your project(only this SmartTablayout part) with me.[ sadegh69@gmail.com]. I would happy if you consider my problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740786/why-this-tab-layout-not-changing-its-tabs-by-moving-related-pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of your `onCreate` method:

`yourViewPagerObject.setCurrentItem(1);`

See if this works in your case (I also use [Smart Tab Layout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)).